# How to "create a basic sample project" with npx hardhat. Missing option

Tags: solidity, hardhat, decentralized-applications

When I type npx hardhat in my terminal it does not give me the option to "create a basic sample project." does anyone know how to get this to appear? it currently only says
"Welcome to Hardhat v2.14.0

? What do you want to do? …
Create a JavaScript project
Create a TypeScript project
Create an empty hardhat.config.js"

i tried to look online and didnt find much that could help. please help!

Answer (score 0):

You are right there.

> To create the sample project, run `npx hardhat` in your project folder

And either choose JavaScript or TypeScript project which will give you a simple but complete project with contracts, deplyoment scripts and tests. See [here](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/getting-started#overview).